# How to change the content according to the location in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, geolocation, location, drupal-taxonomy

For example, if the user opens www.example.com in any country say US, the content should change according to user location .

If the user visits the site in Los Angeles the title should be "Los Angeles" and block content should be according to the taxonomy term city.

I'm new to drupal. So, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

These two modules should help you achieve this:

- [GeoIP](https://drupal.org/project/geoip)
- [Context GeoIP](https://drupal.org/project/context_geoip)